# projects using both angular material and kendo ui?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, themes, angular-material

I am very curious to know whether anyone has tried to use both **[angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/)** (for angular 1.x) and **[kendo ui](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/)** components in the same project, and if so, then:

1. what were the conflicts, if any, they experienced with respect to `css` and/or `javascript`, and
2. because both libraries have a certain amount of cross-over in terms of similar components, what was your thought process when determining which library to use for a component?

While kendo-ui does have a few "[material](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder/)" based themes, I don't see them following the [google material design](https://material.io/guidelines/) spec nearly as close as angular-material does.

Answer (score 2):

I am also using both, Kendo und Material Design, in my desktop client project.

I use Material Design for the general website structure

- toolbar
- sidebar,
- navigation, etc.

and Kendo UI components

- buttons,
- forms, etc.

for everything else. I imported CSS declarations from both.

The only component I use from Material Design is the Snackbar as I think it works better with the common workflow of desktop applications.

So far i have not experienced any conflicts.